# Odd test method failure - Windows security

Tags: c#, security, unit-testing

I'm probably being blind, but this has me stumped. The following unit test fails on my local machine (but not on our build server) with a  System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void UserPreferences_LocalApplicationDataPath_PathAlwaysExists()
    {

        //setup: get the proposed path and then delete the bottom folder and any existing files
        string logPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        string actual = System.IO.Path.Combine(logPath, @"Autoscribe\Matrix\Gemini");

        //if the folder is there, first delete it
        if (Directory.Exists(actual))
        {
            //log some information about what is going on

            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to delete " + actual + " as user " + Environment.UserName);
            Directory.Delete(actual, true); // <-THROWS EXCEPTION HERE
            Console.WriteLine("Deleted");
        }

        //action
        actual = UserPreferencesManager.LocalApplicationDataPath;

        //assert that getting the path forces it to be created.
        Assert.IsTrue(Directory.Exists(actual));
    }
```

The reported Environment.UserName value is the Windows user who 'owns' the local AppData folder. Why can't folder be deleted? Oddly I don't have this problem on all machines that the test is run on (all Windows 7).

Comment: Hate to ask, but are you sure it's empty? If it's not empty, I'm pretty sure you'll get blocked.

Comment: Are you able to create/delete the same folder `manually` in your system?
Does it ask for `admin` privileges?

Comment: The folder does have a file in it but the Directory.Delete(...,true) should take care of that. It also has a file in it on the build server, where I do not have this problem.

Comment: I am running as an administrator anyway, and I can create/delete the folder manually. it seems only to be the test that has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to delete the folder locally because you still have other applications running that access files in it. Maybe you have opened a notepad to check a logfile in this folder?

The build server does not have these problems, because there are no users or processes actually "working" on the machine.

Comment: Good point, but I do not have anything open other than Vis Studio where the tests are being run. That was the firs thing I thought of, and I have checked carefully.